# Delete subquery with alias MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery, alias

I have a problem with this delete query:

```
DELETE r 
FROM table AS r 
WHERE r.stoptime IS NULL 
  and r.address IN 
    (select address from table where starttime <= r.starttime and stoptime > r.starttime)
```

I get the following error:

Error : You can't specify target table 'r' for update in FROM clause.

My goal is to delete records that the starttime is contained in another record but I got an error with the alias in the subquery.

Somebody know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use JOINS like this:

```
 DELETE r
  FROM `table` r 
  JOIN `table` t ON t.id = r.id
 WHERE t.starttime <= r.starttime and t.stoptime > r.starttime
   AND r.stoptime IS NULL
```

Comment: I think this code is working perfectly for me, but another question, I am not sure if it is possible: I want to add ORDER BY username LIMIT 100 clauses. But I got errors. Is it possible?

Comment: @AndroidLearner:- No you cannot use that. See the [Delete docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html): `For the multiple-table syntax, DELETE deletes from each tbl_name the rows that satisfy the conditions. In this case,` **ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.**

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my day. Thanks.